How to write test case for calling Error function inside .catch() using jest in react native
I am writing test case using jest in react native typescript application. i have code like this:-
  const onError = () => {
    setWifiStatus(NetworkStatus.NOT_CONNECTED);
    setWifiDetails(null);
  };

  const handleRefresh = () => {
    refresh()
      .then(state => {
        onSuccess(state);
      })
      .catch(() => {
        onError();
      });
  };

This is my code. inside handleRefresh function, we are calling refresh function from the library. it returns promises, i want to handle .catch().i am not able to write test case how to called onError() inside .catch(). also in onError() i am updating 2 state variables.I am using typescript in my application.
